# How to select records from two tables, COALESCE Values that do not exist in Table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables with the following data:

`table1  (palletid, caseshipped, orderid)`

```
palletid   |  (caseshipped)  | orderid
2002057    |    10.00        |  146
2002058    |    50.00        |  146
2002059    |    25.00        |  146
2002058    |    10.00        |  142
```

and

`table2  (palletid,caseshipping, orderid)`

```
palletid   |  (caseshipping)  |  orderid
2002055    |    0.00          |    146
2002056    |    25.00         |    146
2002057    |    10.00         |    146
2002058    |    50.00         |    146
2002059    |    25.00         |    146
2002060    |    75.00         |    146
2002058    |    10.00         |    142
```

Result expected from query `tableresult(DISTINCT(table2.palletid),COALESCE(table1.caseshipped,0), orderid`

```
palletid   |  (caseshipped)  | orderid
2002055    |    0.00         |  146
2002056    |    0.00         |  146
2002057    |    10.00        |  146 
2002058    |    50.00        |  146
2002059    |    25.00        |  146
2002060    |    0.00         |  146
```

I have the following query, but I get one repeated `table2.palletid` with the wrong `table1.caseshipped` and wrong `table2.orderid`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT table2.palletid, 
COALESCE(table1.caseshipped,0) FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.palletid=table1.PalletID
WHERE table2.orderid = 146
```

Result from query:

```
palletid   |  (caseshipped) | orderid
2002055    |    0.00        |   146
2002056    |    0.00        |   146
2002057    |    10.00       |   146
2002058    |    10.00       |   146       Value should not appear(orderid=142)
2002058    |    50.00       |   146       
2002059    |    25.00       |   146
2002060    |    0.00        |   146
```

How can I correct the query to get the expected result? Why am I getting a repeated result?

I've searched around to look for a similar question, and could not find this specific situation, but if this has been ask, please just redirect me to the post.

Comment: What are the input values..?

Comment: Either of your table (table1 or table2) has 2 records for palletid=2002058. This is causing multiple records in your result. If there are multiple records then which record you want to keep in your resuly?

Comment: I don't see a column called `table1.CaseCount` in your table definition.

Comment: @XEngineer No, i already checked that and it is not the case.

Comment: @Eric thank you i corrected my mistake.

Comment: Table1 has a duplicate value for PalletID 2002058

Comment: Run these. Which one returns two results? One of them does. `select palletid, caseshipped from table1 where palletid = 2002058` and `select palletid,caseshipping from table2 where palletid = 2002058`

Comment: For the sample data you posted your query does not produce the repeated value. So you have not described the problem correctly.

Comment: @EricBrandt that is the first thing i checked and once again NO DUPLICATE VALUE, i would not be asking the question if it was that obvious.

Comment: JuanG, then there's something else going on because, as noted by @forpas, the sample data provided does not produce the results reported when the query shown is run.

Comment: @EricBrandt , I dropped the tables, and recreated them both, and the query worked correctly, so i want ahead and also added an orderid Column to both tables, and added the value palletid=2002058 twice in both tables, but with different orderid, then i tried to query this by orderid, but i get duplicate again, any ideas now with a different sample of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing one condition in your `ON` clause..

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.palletid, 
COALESCE(table1.caseshipped,0) FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.orderID = table1.orderID AND table2.palletid=table1.PalletID
WHERE table2.orderid = 146
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not repeated  result in your result  .. In SQL the distinct clause work for each value in a row not on a single column value

if you want only  a result for each value of a column you must use group by and aggregation functio eg min() or max()

```
SELECT  table2.palletid, 
max(COALESCE(table1.CaseCount,0)) 
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.palletid=table1.PalletID
GROUP BY table2.palletid
```

looking to your last sample seems you are looking for  the min () group by palleid of the union  between the 2 tables

```
selet  palletid,  min(caseshipped), orderid
from(
  select  palletid,  caseshipped, orderid
  from table1
  union  
  select  palletid,  caseshipped, orderid
  from table1
) t  
where orderid = 145 
group by palletid
```

Comment: I'm sorry i just corrected the expected Result. the repeated result is palletid= 2002058

Comment: based on your sample my answer  should seect your expected  result and for palletid= 2002058  should select the row with 50.00

Comment: yes in this case yes, but if the amount in table1 was   8.00 for example, I when I used your code, I got a value of  10.00 in palletid=2002058 so what to do here

Comment: then  your question and your sample is not clear  ..and you last comment is not coherent with  your question ..

Comment: I corrected the data sample, and added another column to both tables, please let me know if now it's clear

Comment: answer updated  .. with asuggestion ..hope is what you are loking for

Comment: thanks, what i'm looking for exactly it's all the palletid, that exist in table2, with the caseshipped that exist table1 with table1.palletid=table2.palletid  and if not exist in table1, then use the value of 0=caseshipped for those numbers,

Answer (score 0):

Just add a join condition on **orderid**. Your join on palletid is resulting into many-to-many join and that's why you see 2 rows, they are actually 4 rows (2 for orderid 146, 2 for orderid 142) but since you have filter on orderid 146 you see only 2 rows. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.palletid,
COALESCE(table1.caseshipped,0), table2.orderid FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 
  ON table2.palletid=table1.PalletID
  AND table2.orderid = table1.orderid
WHERE table2.orderid = 146
```